# Find the section or page of a VBA controls object

Tags: ms-access, vba

How can I identify if a controls object (such as acTextBox) is member of a pages collection in VBA?

When a control object has the focus, a function is called to move the focus to the next control.tabindex based on the type of key which is used. I managed to do this with Sendkeys "{TAB}", but I want to change this since this method constantly disables NUMLOCK on the keyboard.

So far the function below works, but the procedure considers all controls in a form. It should only consider the controls within the same section or page where the function is called from. To accomplish this I need to know if the active control is located within a page and/or section and if it is, the name or index of this page/section. I cannot find the code to do this.

```
Public Function GotoNextTab()
    Dim ctlNext, ctlCurrent As Control
    Dim frmCurrent As Form
    Dim lngNextTab As Long
    Set frmCurrent = Screen.Activeform
    Set ctlCurrent = Forms(frmCurrent.Name).ActiveControl

    lngNextTab = Val(ctlCurrent.TabIndex) + 1

    Do Until lngNextTab = frmCurrent.Controls.Count
        For Each ctlNext In frmCurrent.Controls
            Select Case ctlNext.ControlType
                Case acCheckBox, _
                     acComboBox, _
                     acCommandButton, _
                     acListBox, _
                     acOptionButton, _
                     acSubform, _
                     acTabCtl, _
                     acTextBox, _
                     acToggleButton
                        If ctlNext.TabIndex = lngNextTab Then
                            If ctlNext.TabStop = True Then
                                'Make sure that the focus can be set here!
                                If ctlNext.Visible = True And ctlNext.Enabled = True Then
                                    ctlNext.SetFocus
                                    Exit Function
                                Else
                                    'Focus could not be moved, so increase lngNextTab
                                    lngNextTab = lngNextTab + 1
                                End If
                            Else
                                'This was the last tab, so exit
                                Exit Function
                            End If
                        End If
            End Select
        Next ctlNext
    Loop
End Function
```

Comment: What do you mean by *pages collection* concerning forms? Do you mean this [Access 2003 feature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa210669(v=office.11).aspx)? If you can share a screenshot of this interesting form. And where is this function being called? What trigger event (OnOpen, OnClick, AfterUpdate)?

Comment: I work in v2010, but yes, that is exactly what I mean. The controls are located on different pages in a tab control object. The range of tabindex values is limited to the number of controls within a tab page (otherwise I would just simply number them continuously). That's why I want to know on which page ( Pages(Index) ) the control is located,

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the [TabControl.Pages()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243813(v=office.12).aspx) collection to access controls on specific tab pages.

Below is an example to: first find the corresponding page of active control looping through all controls in each tab page; then assign current page and loop through all its controls. Checking by name is reliable since every control with or without tabs on a form must be unique.

```
...
Dim currpage As Page
Dim tabCtrl As Control
Dim pagename As String

' FIND CURRENT PAGE OF ACTIVE CONTROL
For Each currpage In Forms!myForm!TabCtl.Pages
    For Each tabctrl In currpage.Controls
       If tabctrl.Name = ctlCurrent.Name
           pagename = currpage.Name
       End If
    Next tabctrl     
Next currpage

If Len(pagename) > 0 Then
   ' ASSIGN CURRENT TAB PAGE
   Set currpage = Forms!myForm!mytabCtl.Pages(pagename)

   ' LOOP THROUGH ALL CONTROLS ON CURRENT PAGE  
   For Each tabctrl In currpage.Controls
       '...PROCESS EACH CTRL OF CURRENT TAB PAGE
   Next tabctrl      

   Set tabctrl = Nothing
   Set currpage = Nothing
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your answer, this helped me in the right direction. I discovered that the parent property always refers to the control up one level (which is in this case the Page object). I still have to insert a feature to return to the first available control within the parent controls collection when the last control is reached. So far it gave not the result I wanted, so I will stick with the procedure as it is now.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    KeyPreview = True
End Sub

Private Sub Form_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    Dim ctl As Control
    If KeyCode = vbKeyReturn Then
        'Disregard textboxes with multiple lines
        Set ctl = Me.ActiveControl
        If ctl.ControlType = acTextBox Then
            If ctl.EnterKeyBehavior Then
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
        GotoNextTab
    End If
End Sub

Public Function GotoNextTab()
' This function will move the focus to the next control if
' a) This control is a specified type
' b) The control is visible and enabled
' c) The control has a tabstop set to true
'
' If the controls are within a page (TabControl), the focus is cycled within the controls on that page.
' The function disregards sections as it is assumed that there is no need to cycle controls on a form header or footer
' The focus does not cycle within subforms.

On Error Resume Next

    Dim ctlNext as Control
    Dim ctlCurrent As Control
    Dim frmCurrent As Form
    Dim lngNextTab As Long
    Set frmCurrent = Screen.Activeform
    Set ctlCurrent = Forms(frmCurrent.Name).ActiveControl
    If ctlCurrent.Parent.ControlType = acOptionGroup Then
        Set ctlCurrent = ctlCurrent.Parent
    End If
    lngNextTab = ctlCurrent.TabIndex

    Do Until lngNextTab > ctlCurrent.Parent.Controls.Count
        lngNextTab = lngNextTab + 1
        For Each ctlNext In ctlCurrent.Parent.Controls
            Select Case ctlNext.ControlType
                Case acCheckBox, _
                    acComboBox, _
                    acCommandButton, _
                    acListBox, _
                    acSubform, _
                    acTabCtl, _
                    acTextBox, _
                    acToggleButton, _
                    acOptionGroup
                        If ctlNext.TabIndex = lngNextTab Then
                            'Make sure that the focus can be set here!
                            If ctlNext.TabStop = True And ctlNext.Visible = True And ctlNext.Enabled = True Then
                                ctlNext.SetFocus
                                Exit Function
                            Else
                                Exit For 'restart for/next and search the next value
                            End If
                        End If
            End Select
        Next ctlNext
    Loop
End Function
```